# Кроссплатформенный метод управления процессами

Tags: c++, boost, процесс

О чём речь. Требуется:

1. Запускать приложение с *.exe файла с параметрами(параметры передающиеся в main программы и параметры запуска приложения(свернутое окно, безоконный режим))
2. Возможность узнать, что процесс все еще работает и, возможность его завершать(если он работает и больше не нужен) и перезапускать(завершился сам или с ошибкой - запустить опять)
3. Возможность использовать эти средства как на Unix(например, Debian 8), так и на Windows.

Можно и средствами boost.

Хотелось бы увидеть еще и пример использования по типу следующего:

```
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        bool state = true;
        //запускаем копию этого приложения с более чем 3 параметрами
        int i = 1;
        while (state)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            if (/*приложение завершилось*/)
            {
                //запускаем още одну копию с более чем 3 параметрами
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 3) { state = false; }
        }
        std::cout << "Finished";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "COPY!";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Уточните, вам нужно именно *управление* запущеным процессом, или просто проверка его существования?

Comment: @PinkTux для начала, проверка его существования

Comment: Если `boost`, то смотреть в сторону [boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). Если просто проверять, то через PID-файлы.

Comment: В boost нет подходящей библиотеки. boost.interprocess - это только взаимодействие (мутексы, разделяемая память, очереди сообщений и ь.д.). boost.process ( http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/ ) так и не вошел в библиотеку, у автора не хватило терпения доотлаживать.

Comment: Может быть поможет [Boost.Process](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/process.html)